# Can you build an expression inside of a custom code function in Report Builder?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I need to provide my RDL files to teammates so that they can make minor customizations for each client. One of the ways I thought I might improve the efficiency is if I could build more complex expressions inside of custom code functions so that they can input some simple arguments and have the function handle the "heavy lifting" of adjusting the expression accordingly.

This is a very simple example, and not one I would take this step for, but I thought it the easiest place to start figuring out if I can make this work. For instance, in a tablix we want a count returned based on a value where the value is customized per client (and isn't a parameter).

```
=Count(iif(trim(Fields!Category.Value)="OPTIONA",1,nothing))
```

Is there a way I could build a function so that my teammates would just need to enter the following?

```
=Code.CustomFunction("OPTIONA")
```

My understanding is that the custom code in Report Builder can't query datasets, or at least not in the way that an expression within a tablix would be able to. I've built custom functions that work with the results of an expression added as the argument, but I can't seem to wrap my head around if there's a way to construct an expression within a custom function and pass it back to the expression.

For instance:

```
Public Function CustomFunction(field As String) As String
    Dim customExpression As String = "Count(iif(trim(Fields!Category.Value)=" & field & ",1,nothing))"
    Return customExpression
End Function
```

As expected, this just returns a string with the text of the expression, but not an executed expression. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible with Report Builder?

Or, as an alternative approach, can I somehow place variables at the beginning of an expression that are used later so that anyone else working on the expression just needs to worry about the beginning? Essentially create multiple custom functions and call them later on?

```
=Code.CustomFunction("OPTIONA",Count(iif(trim(Fields!Category.Value)=Code.CustFunc01(),1,nothing)))
```

Honestly not sure how I would go about building the functions themselves from here.

Comment: My guess would be no. I think you would have to pass in the dataset for example and then basically recreate the functionality of the expression you were trying to emulate which personally I would not think would warrant the effort involved. Other, smarter people may know better though!

Comment: @AlanSchofield - That's my assumption as well, but like you I'm always hoping there's someone smarter out there that's come up with a creative solution.

Comment: Which part of the expression are you trying to edit per client here?  It kinda looks like you want to set a different value for `OPTIONA` but also in some parts that you want the whole expression to be different somehow?  Could you add a couple examples for how the expression to be evaluated could be altered for 2 or 3 different clients?

Comment: @iamdave - I just want my teammates to specify a value for the string represented by "OPTIONA". Instead of having to read through an expression to find where to put "OPTIONA", I was hoping to have a simple function where that's the only argument they need to see/worry about and the custom function would build out the reset behind the scenes.

Comment: @BobbyScon  Why don't you want to use report parameters for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function instead of the related field. The function takes the field string as an argument and the filter string for which will increase the counter. Finally it returns the  original field value

```
    Private Dim Counter As Integer
    
    Public Function SetCounter( Expr As String, Filter As String)  As String
    
    If Expr = Filter Then Counter = Counter + 1
    
    Return Expr
    
    End Function
    
    Public Function GetCounter( )  As Integer
    Return Counter 
    
    End Function
```

For the field value you can use the following expression (yellow color)

```
=Code.SetCounter( Fields!MyString.Value,"OPTION A")
```

To get the counter value you can either use the following expression calling a function (orange color)

```
= Code.GetCounter()
```

Or make the variable public and use `Code.Counter` as the expression

[image]